# Timestamps during MS Build

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, database-project

I have a single solution with multiple database projects and an SSIS projects. The entire build and deploy portion takes a few minutes especially because we deploy unit test data along with the build.

Does Visual Studio 2008 allow me to display timestamps the output window of the build so I can keep track of things?

I know I can execute SQL Scripts during Post-Deployment and Pre-Deployment, but unless I really have to, I do not want to go around adding SQL scripts to all projects in my solution for a generic thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that any [default loggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx) have support for this but other loggers available to. Just search for something like "*MSBuild XML Logger*".

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging led to finding this solution;

Tools >> Options >> Expand "Projects and Solutions" then select "Build and Run"

Set the MSBuild project build output verbosity to "Normal". This will timestamp the start of the build process. Not ideal to have to scroll to the top but at least each build clears the build output so the timestamp will always be at the top.